# What causes "Can't find Symbol" and how to fix it?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've been trying to figure this out, I've run it in different programs so it's definitely in the code. Probably something easy too. The error says

> Password2.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
>             if(pw.equals(password))
>                          ^
>   symbol:   variable password
>   location: class Password2.EnterButtonHandler
>   1 error

Here is the code:

```
// Password1.java

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Password2 extends JFrame // inherits from the JFrame class 
{
    // static final variables to hold frame dimensions (in pixels) 
    private static final int WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 120;

    //declare labels, fields, buttons, etc.
    private JLabel enterLabel, validLabel, resultLabel;
    private JTextField pwTextField;
    private JButton enterB, clearB;

    private EnterButtonHandler ebHandler;
    private ClearButtonHandler cbHandler;

    public Password2() // constructor defines frame 
    { 
            setTitle( "Password Checker" ); // set the title of the frame
        setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT ); // set the frame size

        // prepare the container 
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GridLayout aGrid = new GridLayout( 3, 2, 5, 5 ); // create a 3 row 2 column layout
        pane.setLayout( aGrid ); // set the layout for the frame

        String password = "hello";

        //instantiate JLabels
        enterLabel = new JLabel("Enter Password: ");
        validLabel = new JLabel("Validation: ");
        resultLabel = new JLabel("");

        //instantiate text fields
        pwTextField = new JPasswordField( 30 );

        //instantiate buttons
        enterB = new JButton("Enter");
        clearB = new JButton("Clear");

        //initialize button handler
        ebHandler = new EnterButtonHandler();
        enterB.addActionListener(ebHandler);

        //initialize button handler
        cbHandler = new ClearButtonHandler();
        clearB.addActionListener(cbHandler);


        pane.add(enterLabel);
        pane.add(pwTextField);
        pane.add(validLabel);
        pane.add(resultLabel);
        pane.add(enterB);
        pane.add(clearB);

        //calls center frame method
        centerFrame( WIDTH, HEIGHT );

    }// end constructor

    //methood to center GUI on screen
    public void centerFrame( int frameWidth, int frameHeight)
    {
        //create toolkit object
        Toolkit aToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        //create a dimension object with user screen information
        Dimension screen = aToolkit.getScreenSize();

        //assign x, y position of upper left corner of frame
        int xUpperLeft = ( screen.width - frameWidth ) / 2;
        int yUpperLeft = ( screen.height - frameHeight ) / 2;

        //method to position frame on user's screen
        setBounds( xUpperLeft, yUpperLeft, frameWidth, frameHeight );
    }

    private class EnterButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String pw = pwTextField.getText();

            if(pw.equals(password))
            {
                resultLabel.setText("Password Accepted");
                pwTextField.setText("");
            }
            else
            {
                resultLabel.setText("Password Rejected");
                pwTextField.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
    private class ClearButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            resultLabel.setText("");
            pwTextField.setText("");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        JFrame aPassword2 = new Password2(); // create the JFrame object
        aPassword2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        aPassword2.setVisible(true);
    }
    } // end of class
```

Comment: @RobW Trying to decide if that's sarcasm -->

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read the error message, love the error message.

It takes some practice, but after awhile it's easy to see it more clearly: just read across the bold text below as a sentence :)

> error: **cannot find symbol** [...]
>
> symbol: variable **password**
>
> location: **[in]** class Password2.**EnterButtonHandler**

There is nothing named `password` *in that scope/context* (`EnterButtonHandler`).

Happy coding.

---

Hint: there is a *local* variable with the same name in a *different* scope/context... perhaps it shouldn't be a *local* variable? See [The Java Tutorial: Variables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for more :)

Answer (score 0):

`password` is local to the `Password2` constructor.

It should either be passed around, or an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your class doesn't have a definition for `password`. Hence, the error when passing it to the `equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the variable `password`, which, as you've coded it, only exists in the `Password2` constructor. You'll need to either make `password` a class member variable or pass it to the constructor of your `Handler` classes, so they can have a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
password
```

is a local variable declared in the constructor of Password2. It is not in scope in your `EnterButtonHandler.actionPerformed method`. Make it an instance variable to resolve.